# TFS Build Service Wizard Failing on 'Edit collection-level information' permission set to Allow

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-server, azure-devops

I'm trying to setup a TFS Build service but the config wizard keeps bombing out on Edit collection-level information permissions, which I have set as required.

There isn't much background information for this, its a new 2003 virtual sever with nothing but TFS build service installed. The only other Warning I get is about no firewall being installed so I cant see that interfering. The section of interest in the log is below.

```
Verify: Verify that the running account has the required Team Foundation Server permissions(TBRUNNINACOUNT): Starting Verification
TF279000: User domain\user.name does not have permission to add members to the Build Services group. To perform this action, the user must have the 'Edit collection-level information' permission set to Allow.
!Verify Error!: TF279000: User domain\user.name does not have permission to add members to the Build Services group. To perform this action, the user must have the 'Edit collection-level information' permission set to Allow.
"Verify: Verify that the running account has the required Team Foundation Server permissions(TBRUNNINACOUNT): Exiting Verification with state Completed and result Error"
!Verify Result!: 1 Completed, 0 Skipped: 0 Success, 1 Errors, 0 Warnings
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have no idea where to go from here.

Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as basically I was picking up from where Tom left off.

On the TFS Server used for the source control I added my AD user account to the Project Collection Build Administrators group and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why your Build should edit something on Collection level, but what should solve the problem is to add the permission to the "Project Collection Build Service Accounts". I expect that TBRUNNINACOUNT is member of this group, otherwise the build might fail.

To set the persmission do the following steps:

1. Open Team Explorer
2. connect to the TeamProjectCollection the build service should be used for
3. Right click on the root to get the context menu
4. choose "Team Project Collection Settings -> Security"
5. select the "Project Collection Build Service Accounts"
6. set 'Edit collection-level information' permission
7. Close dialogs by using ok

Now the account has the needed permission and the wizard should run through that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I left the company shortly after so never get a chance to test your answer. +1 consolation prize.

Comment: This is funny.  I've just done the same thing, got the same error, and found this post.  And who was it that posted it, my old colleague @TomRiley

Comment: Neither this nor the above suggestion worked for me.

Comment: Are you running the build service with a domain user? Is that user permitted in TFS? Maybe you could post your error message.